# Lightning Tab - Pass parameters

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am trying to navigate to a Newly setup tab using a lightning component. Component is configured to be used with RecordHome and contains recordId attribute. When navigating to the component, I would like to pass-in a parameter. I tried passing using using URL while firing e.force:navigateToURL event - but it seems like that's NOT going to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an event called force:navigateToComponent. This might help you. But it does not have any documentation.

For example:-

```
navigateToRollCall : function(component, event, helper) {
var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
    evt.setParams({
        componentDef: "c:AttendanceRollCall",
        componentAttributes: {
            programId: component.get("v.program.Id")
        }
    });
    evt.fire();    
}
```

Comment: It is not wise to use undocumented event.After some time it might not work,when salesforce removes it from public access without notifying.

Comment: You are always welcome Bhuvan. For time being, this is the only method.

Answer (score 0):

navigateToRollCall : function(component, event, helper) {
var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
    evt.setParams({
        componentDef: "c:AttendanceRollCall",
        componentAttributes: {
            programId: component.get("v.program.Id")
        }
    });
    evt.fire();
}
After calling this function in aura component.How to get the value of programId in LWC. I am stuck in similar type of scenario.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, this is not an answer to the original question. Please, if you have your own question ask it as such.